# How to read multiend raml file in Java

Tags: java, api, parsing, mocking, raml

I have a raml file with multiend points. I have one endpoint named as /customer/{customerId} which further have nested endpoint /accounts/{accountId}

How to parse this raml file and fetch methods/body/response from each endpoints

Comment: This site will not do your work for you.  What have tried?  Give us the base code you have written so we can see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To read a raml file into Java we have to add below depended into our project Pom

Raml-parser-2

This dependency will give us RamlModelBuilder
By using this builder we can pass the raml file to it and get result into RamlModelResult class

This RamlModelResult class has getApiV08() method which return api object

Using this api we can get resources/ endpoints present in raml file.

For nested resource, we need to fetch resourcelist under each resource in loop

Once we get the resource we can get methodlist, request, headers, response from each endpoint.